# Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row - Functions

Tags: mysql, function

Can anyone help me with this code?

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS dislike;

DELIMITER //
CREATE  FUNCTION dislike(disliked_id int(11)) RETURNS CHAR
BEGIN
DECLARE disliked_songs CHAR;

IF disliked_id = 1 THEN
    SET disliked_songs = (SELECT song_title from songs  
    where like_flag IN (SELECT like_flag from songs where like_flag= 1));

ELSE 
    SET disliked_songs =  (SELECT song_title from songs  
    where like_flag IN (SELECT like_flag from songs where like_flag= 0));

END IF;

RETURN disliked_songs;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;

select dislike(1);
```

I am trying to call the the function but doing so returns an error

Comment: Don't be shy.  What is the error?

Comment: What exactly is it you think those queries do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery is returning more than one row.  You need to return a single value.  There are various ways:

- Use `min()` or `max()`.
- Use `limit`.
- Use `group_concat()`.

Something like this:

```
SELECT disliked_songs := group_concat(song_title )
FROM songs  
WHERE like_flag = 1;
```

I'm not sure what useful function this does.  You also run the risk of overflowing a character string, if the table `songs` has more than a few rows.

I suspect that you want `disliked_id` in the subquery somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting the variable 'disliked_songs' to something, you can't have more than one possible value. In other words, your subquery

```
(SELECT song_title from songs where like_flag IN (SELECT like_flag from songs where like_flag= 1))
```

is bringing back more than one song title. Since you are taking that song title and applying it to a single value

```
SET disliked_songs =
```

there can only be ONE title returned. Check out the results from each of those sub-queries and see if one of them is returning more than one result. If so you have to narrow down the results by adding additional WHERE clauses.

Comment: How should I save more than one rows in a variable? I am trying to return the liked or disliked songs. dislike(1) should return liked songs and vice versa. Hope I am clear. Thanks Michael.

Comment: @Abhishek you cannot store/return multiple values in a single variable (other than concatenating strings together as Gordon's answer suggests).